# How to create an argument captor for a Map object in mockito in java?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

How to create an argument captor for `Map<String, SomeCustomClass>`?

I have the code that follows the following pattern:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CompoundClass {

   public CompoundClass (String a, String b){
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
   }

   public String a;
   public String b;
}

public class SubClass {
    public void doSomeThingSubClass(Map<String, CompoundClass> mapSb) {
        ...
    }
}

public class Example {

    public SubClass sb;

    public Example(SubClass sb) {
        this.sb = sb;
    }

    public void doSomeThing () {
        Map<String, CompoundClass> mapSb = new HashMap<>();
        mapSb.put("x", new CompoundClass("aa","bb"));
        sb.doSomeThingSubClass(mapSb);
    }
}
```

And I want to test if the method `doSomethingSubClass(mapSb)` was called, whereby I need to be able to check with what argument it was called. For this purpose I have the following unit test:

```java
@Test
void TestDoSomehing(){
    SubClass sb = mock(SubClass.class);
    
    Example ex = new Example(sb);
    
    ArgumentCaptor<Map<String, CompoundClass>> argCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Map<String, CompoundClass>.class);

    ex.doSomeThing();

    verify(sb).doSomeThingSubClass(argCaptor.capture());
    
    System.out(argCaptor.getValue().get('x').a);
}
```

The problem is that the above initialization of the argCaptor produces the following error message: "Cannot select from parametrized type". Therefore, the question is how to declare an initialize in a correct way the argument captor for a map object like `Map<String, SomeCustomeClass>`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it either:

with @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

```
  @Test
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  void TestDoSomething(){
    SubClass sb = mock(SubClass.class);

    Example ex = new Example(sb);

    ArgumentCaptor<Map<String, CompoundClass>> argCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Map.class);

    ex.doSomeThing();

    verify(sb).doSomeThingSubClass(argCaptor.capture());

    System.out.println(argCaptor.getValue().get("x").a);
  }
```

or with junit5 and @Captor annotation:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance.Lifecycle;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Captor;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_METHOD)
public class TestDoSomething {

  @Captor
  private ArgumentCaptor<Map<String, CompoundClass>> argCaptor;

  @Test
  void TestDoSomething2(){
    SubClass sb = mock(SubClass.class);

    Example ex = new Example(sb);

    ex.doSomeThing();

    verify(sb).doSomeThingSubClass(argCaptor.capture());

    System.out.println(argCaptor.getValue().get("x").a);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also just do argumentCaptor<Map<String,String>>() -> no @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") and no @Captor of junit5

Comment: @JustAnotherDev: that lead to an exception, that the variable `argCaptor` is not initialised / a `NullPointerException` when calling `argCaptor.capture()`. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @MartindelNecesario, if you need help, could you show a snippet of code where we can see some more context. It seems that you didn't initialize your argCaptor, before passing it in a function call.

Comment: I see my mistake. I didn't notice the @Captor annotation. So, it will be initialised via Mockito, correct?

Comment: Yes indeed it should work like that

Answer (score 4):

You can use Mockito's `Captor` annotation to declare a parameterized instance of `ArgumentCaptor`.

For example, the following test compiles and outputs `aa`:

```
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Map<String, CompoundClass>> argCaptor;

@Test
void TestDoSomehing(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    SubClass sb = mock(SubClass.class);

    Example ex = new Example(sb);

    ex.doSomeThing();

    verify(sb).doSomeThingSubClass(argCaptor.capture());

    System.out.println(argCaptor.getValue().get("x").a);
}
```

From [the Javadocs](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.2/org/mockito/Captor.html):

> One of the advantages of using `@Captor` annotation is that you can avoid warnings related capturing complex generic types.